# Pass verbose Excel's in-built function to a Cell using VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I'm having trouble in passing a built-in Excel function to a cell. It keeps returning `"Run-time error '1004': Application-defined or object-defined error".`

Basically what I'm trying to do is create a dynamic calculus of average/mean using VBA.

```
With Sheets("TC7_DATA")
    LastColumn = .Cells(4, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    For i = 1 To Rows.Count
        If (.Cells(i, 3).Value = "Average Value") Then
            .Cells(i, LastColumn).Value = "=IF(AND(.Cells(i-3; LastColumn)=0; .Cells(i-2; LastColumn)=0; .Cells(i-1; LastColumn)=0);" - - - "; AVERAGE(.Cells(i-3; LastColumn), .Cells(i-3; LastColumn)))"
        End If
    Next i
End With
```

If I insert the value without the `"="` in the front of the function, it interprets as text and nothing goes wrong (except that the function don't actually works, of course).
I tried to add `"="` in the front of the cell without using VBA and the function works correctly. If I concatenate USING VBA

```
.Cells(i, LastColumn).Value = "=" & .Cells(i, LastColumn).Value
```

The error returns.

How can I pass a VERBOSE Excel in-built function:

```
("=IF(2>3; "True"; "False")")
```

to a Cell using VBA?

Comment: You need to concatenate the string portion of formula and variables  so it that will form the correct excel formula, Also, for setting formula use `.Formula` instead `.Value` - Something like `"=IF(AND(" & .cells(i-3 & ";" & LastColumn...` and so on

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `.Formula` instead.

Few other points:

- You don't need spaces in your `If` statement like some other
  languages unless you want to group statements together
- Your `For` loop doesn't explicitly define which sheet it should be
  counting the rows on. Use `.Rows.Count` instead to specify the sheet 
  `Sheets("TC7_DATA")` or declare another sheet
- Your `For` loop also will loop through every row in the sheet
  (possibly all 1,048,576 of them). This is incredibly verbose. I'd
  recommend just looping through the ones you actually need instead.
  You already get the `LastColumn` why not get the `LastRow` as well
  using something like `LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row`
  and use this value in your for loop instead

---

```
With Sheets("TC7_DATA")
    LastColumn = .Cells(4, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    For i = 1 To Rows.Count
        If .Cells(i, 3).Value = "Average Value" Then
            .Cells(i, LastColumn).Formula = "=IF(AND(" & .Cells(i - 3, LastColumn) & "=0; " & .Cells(i - 2, LastColumn) & "=0; " & .Cells(i - 1, LastColumn) & "=0);"" - --""; AVERAGE(" & .Cells(i - 3, LastColumn) & ", " & .Cells(i - 3, LastColumn) & "))"
        End If
    Next i
End With
```

Comment: Tom, thank you for the tips, I'll defintely consider each one of them. But unfortunately the `.Formula` didn't solve my problem. It keeps returning the same error, even if I just put a simple formula `"=IF(2>3;0;1)"`

Comment: Tom, problem solved. Thank you very much for you help, I couldn't figure out the ".Formula" statement without you, so I'm upvoting you. Just for curiosity, I had to change any `;` to `,`, like `"=IF(2>3, 0, 1)"` inside the in-built formula, then it worked.

Comment: @GermanoLodi It is the system default setting for list separator.

Answer (score 0):

You have to write to the Formula property, not the Value property.

Example:

```
Sheets("CTC7_DATA").[A11].Formula ="=IF(2>3; "True"; "False")"
```